# Why is my partial not rails rendering properly?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, partials

I want to add comments without having to refresh the page in my app.  However, my partial does no load properly with the JS functionality I am implementing.

I am getting no errors in my log or console, and the comment shows once I refresh the page, but it does not happen without a refresh.

Also, when I just write JS to append the last comment to the win_com id, the code works. I'd like the HTML to dynamically show the current state of the comment partial via JS rather than just append the last comment. Any help would be appreciated! Here's my code:

comments_controller.rb:

```
def create
    @window = Window.find(params[:window_id])
    @comment = @window.comments.build(comment_params)
    @comment.user_id = current_user.id

    if @comment.save
        respond_to do |format|
            format.html { redirect_to post_path(@post) }
            format.js 
        end
    end
end
```

views/windows/show.html.erb: (part of a larger view)

```
<div class="row col-md-7" id="win_com">
    <h4>User Comments</h4>
    <%= render partial: '/windows/comment', collection: @comments %>
</div>
```

views/windows/_comment.html.erb:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row col-md-7">
        <p><%= comment.body %></p> 
        <p><%= link_to "Delete", [comment.window, comment], method: :delete,
                                                            data: {confirm: "Are you sure?"} %></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

views/comments/create.js.erb:

```
$('#win_com').html("<%= j render(partial:'/windows/comment', collection: @comments)%>");
```

application.js:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

Maybe some key lines from my sever log?:

```
Rendered windows/_comment.html.erb (0.0ms)
Rendered comments/create.js.erb (1.8ms)
```

Comment: Sometimes browser stumbles with string marks in JS responses. If using Chrome open your terminal, go to Network tab and create your comment. You'll see what server is returning and whether browser is stumbling with that.

Comment: $('#win_com').html""; 

This is what I get in response, but I'm not sure what to make of it?

Comment: Try invoke it this way: $('#win_com').html("<%= j render(partial:'/windows/comment', collection: @comments)%>");

Comment: Thank you, I just realized I forgot the parenthesis, however, now all the previous comments disappear and  nothing shows in the comments section until I refresh. I am getting a similar response in the network tab: $('#win_com').html("");

Comment: Based on what your are doing may I suggest you look into react.rb http://reactrb.org .  This could simplify your life.  I apologize if this is slightly off point, but it a similar suggestion really helped us out a year ago!

Comment: html function will set the content of #win_com with blank (since nothing is being passed as parameter). You may have to use 'append' function.

Comment: Debug your code and check what is being returned by <%= j render(partial:'/windows/comment', collection: @comments)%>

Comment: How do I specifically check what that section of the code is returning? From what it looks like, it seems as though it is returning nothing. What do you mean by 'nothing is being passed as parameter'? Parameter to where?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the @comments instance variable in your controller action create. Rails cannot magically know what it is unless you specify it. Your could change your create action to something like this.

```
def create
    @window = Window.find(params[:window_id])
    @comment = @window.comments.build(comment_params)
    @comment.user_id = current_user.id

    if @comment.save
        @comments = @post.comments //given that this is defined. 
        respond_to do |format|
            format.html { redirect_to post_path(@post) }
            format.js 
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: Yes, I just figured this out from some comments a user left a little bit ago. Thank you for getting back to me, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

.html() will replace all the contents of the target DOM element instead use .append()

Replace this:

```
$('#win_com').html( "<%= j(render(partial:'/windows/comment', collection: @comments)) %>" );
```

With that:

```
$('#win_com').append( "<%= j(render(partial:'/windows/comment', collection: @comments)) %>" );
```